# Microsoft Excel Ceiling function

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, equations

I've got a lot of data that I'm trying to enter into an excel spreadsheet.

All the data in columns after the first are of the form:

> Previous column data * 1.3 {rounded up to the nearest multiple of 5}

The `Previous Column data * 1.3` is easy enough to set up, but I am looking for a way to handle the part of the equation in { } brackets.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel has a built-in ceiling function: `=CEILING(CELL, SIGNIFICANCE)` where CELL is your data (say `A1`) and `SIGNIFICANCE` is your rounding value - 5 in your case.

So if you have the original data in cell `A1` - the complete formula to do what you're asking is:

```
=CEILING(A1*1.3,5)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.